# How to test CRLF inside an HTML tag

Tags: html, character-encoding

I know we can split lines in HTML using br tag but I want to split a line like

```html
<h1>Hello &#0d;&#0a; World</h1>
```

should return,

Hello

World

HTTP support UTF-8. In UTF-8 Line feed is given as 0x0a and carriage return is given as 0x0d. I have checked < and &#3D; inside h1 tags, it is getting converted to its symbol. Is it possible to do carriage return in HTML tag or only HTTP header can be vulnerable to CRLF.

Comment: Why not `hello <br> world`? White-spaces are special in HTML, in most of context they are just interpreted as a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. [Hexadecimal references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#numeric-character-reference-state) start with `&#x`, you are trying to use a hexadecimal value as a decimal.
2. New lines have no more significance than any other white space in HTML by default. You need to use CSS to make them visible (or one of a small number of elements, such as `<pre>`, with default CSS values that do that).

```css
h1 { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<h1>Hello &#x0d;&#x0a; World</h1>
```

---

> I know we can split lines in HTML using br tag but I want to split a line like

You haven't said *why* you want to use character entities for a line break, but using a `<br>` element is probably the right solution to whatever problem you have here.

Comment: Yes got it, I forgot to add the hex indicator 'x' . The main issue was h tags dont display spaces and lines as it is given, we need pre tag for that.I got introduced to a new tag.Thank you for the quick help